# How to recomposit empty DirectoryCatalog for MEF in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mef

I have an application with these step:

1. startup application and ConfigureAggregateCatalog
2. logon user to app
3. download DLL MEF modules to directory called 'Modules'
4. refresh directory catalog -- **there is a problem**

I have empty directory 'Modules' after download dll i tried to load modules but without succes. There is an error on line where I called DirectoryCatalog.Refresh()

> System.ComponentModel.Composition.ChangeRejectedException was
>   unhandled by user code   Message=The composition remains unchanged.
>   The changes were rejected because of the following error(s): The
>   composition produced multiple composition errors, with 14 root causes.
>   The root causes are provided below. Review the
>   CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.
>
> 1) Change in exports prevented by non-recomposable import
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleInitializer..ctor
>   (Parameter="downloadedPartCatalogs",
>   ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.DownloadedPartCatalogCollection")'
>   on part
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleInitializer'.
>
> 2) Change in exports prevented by non-recomposable import
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager.mefFileModuleTypeLoader
>   (ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefFileModuleTypeLoader")'
>   on part
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager'.
>
> 3) Change in exports prevented by non-recomposable import
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager..ctor
>   (Parameter="moduleInitializer",
>   ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModuleInitializer")'
>   on part
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager'.
>
> 4) Change in exports prevented by non-recomposable import
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager.mefFileModuleTypeLoader
>   (ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefFileModuleTypeLoader")'
>   on part
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager'.
>
> 5) Change in exports prevented by non-recomposable import
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager..ctor
>   (Parameter="moduleInitializer",
>   ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModuleInitializer")'
>   on part
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager'.
>
> 6) Change in exports prevented by non-recomposable import
>   'GXBilling.ViewsModels.ShellViewModel.ModuleManager
>   (ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModuleManager")'
>   on part 'GXBilling.ViewsModels.ShellViewModel'.
>
> 7) More than one export was found that matches the constraint
>   '((exportDefinition.ContractName ==
>   "Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.RegionAdapterMappings") AndAlso
>   (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey("ExportTypeIdentity") AndAlso
>   "Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.RegionAdapterMappings".Equals(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))'.
>
> Resulting in: Cannot set import
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.Behaviors.MefDelayedRegionCreationBehavior..ctor
>   (Parameter="regionAdapterMappings",
>   ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.RegionAdapterMappings")'
>   on part
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.Behaviors.MefDelayedRegionCreationBehavior'.
>   Element:
>   Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.Behaviors.MefDelayedRegionCreationBehavior..ctor
>   (Parameter="regionAdapterMappings",
>   ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.RegionAdapterMappings")
>   -->  Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.Behaviors.MefDelayedRegionCreationBehavior
>   -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")
>
> 8) Change in exports prevented by non-recomposable import
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.MefSelectorRegionAdapter..ctor
>   (Parameter="regionBehaviorFactory",
>   ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.IRegionBehaviorFactory")'
>   on part
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.MefSelectorRegionAdapter'.
>
> 9) Change in exports prevented by non-recomposable import
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.MefItemsControlRegionAdapter..ctor
>   (Parameter="regionBehaviorFactory",
>   ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.IRegionBehaviorFactory")'
>   on part
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.MefItemsControlRegionAdapter'.
>
> 10) Change in exports prevented by non-recomposable import
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.MefContentControlRegionAdapter..ctor
>   (Parameter="regionBehaviorFactory",
>   ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.IRegionBehaviorFactory")'
>   on part
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.MefContentControlRegionAdapter'.
>
> 11) More than one export was found that matches the constraint
>   '((exportDefinition.ContractName ==
>   "Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.IRegionViewRegistry") AndAlso
>   (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey("ExportTypeIdentity") AndAlso
>   "Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.IRegionViewRegistry".Equals(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))'.
>
> Resulting in: Cannot set import
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.Behaviors.MefAutoPopulateRegionBehavior..ctor
>   (Parameter="regionViewRegistry",
>   ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.IRegionViewRegistry")'
>   on part
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.Behaviors.MefAutoPopulateRegionBehavior'.
>   Element:
>   Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.Behaviors.MefAutoPopulateRegionBehavior..ctor
>   (Parameter="regionViewRegistry",
>   ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.IRegionViewRegistry")
>   -->  Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.Behaviors.MefAutoPopulateRegionBehavior
>   -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")
>
> 12) Change in exports prevented by non-recomposable import
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleInitializer..ctor
>   (Parameter="downloadedPartCatalogs",
>   ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.DownloadedPartCatalogCollection")'
>   on part
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleInitializer'.
>
> 13) Change in exports prevented by non-recomposable import
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager.mefFileModuleTypeLoader
>   (ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefFileModuleTypeLoader")'
>   on part
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager'.
>
> 14) Change in exports prevented by non-recomposable import
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager..ctor
>   (Parameter="moduleInitializer",
>   ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModuleInitializer")'
>   on part
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager'.
>
> Source=System.ComponentModel.Composition   StackTrace:
>          at System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionResult.ThrowOnErrors(AtomicComposition
>   atomicComposition)
>          at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.OnExportsChanging(ExportsChangeEventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.OnCatalogChanging(Object
>   sender, ComposablePartCatalogChangeEventArgs e)
>          at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ComposablePartCatalogCollection.OnChanging(Object
>   sender, ComposablePartCatalogChangeEventArgs e)
>          at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AggregateCatalog.OnChanging(ComposablePartCatalogChangeEventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ComposablePartCatalogCollection.OnContainedCatalogChanging(Object
>   sender, ComposablePartCatalogChangeEventArgs e)
>          at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.DirectoryCatalog.OnChanging(ComposablePartCatalogChangeEventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.DirectoryCatalog.Refresh()
>          at GXBilling.Bootstrapper.RefreshCatalog() in E:\Projects!New!\GXBilling\GXBilling\Bootstrapper.cs:line 36
>          at GXBilling.ViewsModels.WinLogOnViewModel.FWCore_OnDownloadedModulesCompleted(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   E:\Projects!New!\GXBilling\GXBilling\ViewsModels\WinLogOnViewModel.cs:line
>   168
>          at BillingCore.FWCore.FWCore_ModuleDownloadedCompleted(Object sender, ModuleDownloadedEventArgs e) in
>   E:\Projects!New!\GXBilling\BillingCore\FWCore.cs:line 169
>          at BillingCore.FWCore.client_DownloadFileCompleted(Object sender, DownloadFileCompletedEventArgs e) in
>   E:\Projects!New!\GXBilling\BillingCore\FWCore.cs:line 207
>          at BillingCore.BillingServiceRef.FileTransferServiceClient.OnDownloadFileCompleted(Object
>   state) in E:\Projects!New!\GXBilling\BillingCore\Service
>   References\BillingServiceRef\Reference.cs:line 739
>          at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>          at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
>          at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object
>   state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>          at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>          at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
>          at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
>          at System.Windows.Window.Show()
>          at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()   InnerException:

There is parts of code marked by attribute Import:

```
[Import]
public ShellViewModel ViewModel

[Import(AllowRecomposition = false)]
public IModuleManager ModuleManager { get; set; }

[Import(typeof(IShell), AllowRecomposition = true)]
public IShell MainShell { get; set; }

[ImportingConstructor]
public ModuleImporting(IRegionManager regionManager)
```

That's all. I have not IEnureable or IList or etc. In code. So where is problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refreshing the `DirectoryCatalog` triggers a [recomposition](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Recomposition&referringTitle=Guide). An import on a MEF part can only be recomposed if it is explicitly marked as such, for example like this:

```
[ImportMany(typeof(IFoo),AllowRecomposition=true)]
IEnumerable<IFoo> Foos { private get; set; }
```

If an import is affected by the recomposition, but it isn't marked with `AllowRecomposition=true`, then you get an error: "Change in exports prevented by non-recomposable import".

Also, imports via a constructor don't support recomposition at all. However, [you can work around this](http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2009/03/21/recomposition-and-constructors/).

Comment: Ok, I changed AllowRecomposition value from false to true, but still I have the same error. What's wrong?

Comment: @Musketyr: Did you do it for all 14 imports mentioned in the error message? And did you change them from constructor arguments to property imports, or applied the work-around as described in the blog post I linked to?

Comment: Must be attribute AllowRecomposition at [ImportingConstrucor] too? I cannot added AllowRecomposition to [ImportingConstrucor].

Comment: @Musketyr: Sigh... Please read the last sentence of my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is error like :

> "Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type
>   , key "" "

Then please check whether `[Export]` attribute is specified in `<User Control page>` that we are going to inject in `Region`.

It is small thing but can waste you hours in debugging!

Thanks!
Bassi