# Interception of ChangeRejectedException

Tags: c#

I am trying to load a dll if it is filed in a folder. To do this I do this:

```
FileSystemWatcher filesw = new FileSystemWatcher();
string pathDossier = @"C:\Users\gfauconnier\Documents\Visual Studio 
2013\Projects\PluginAppSolution\PluginApp\bin\Debug\Plugin";
    DirectoryCatalog directoryCatalog;

    public PluginLoader(string path)
    {
        directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(path);

        filesw.Path = pathDossier;
        filesw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        filesw.Filter = "*.*";
        filesw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        filesw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(directoryCatalog);

        _Container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        _Container.ComposeParts(this);
    }

    private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            directoryCatalog.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("refresh ok");
    }
```

The problem is that I end up with the following error that I do not understand:

The composition remains unchanged. The changes were rejected due to the following errors: The composition produced a single compositional error. The initial cause is provided below. For more information, review the CompositionException.Errors property.

1) Modification of the exports prevented by the non-recomposable import 'MyApp.PluginLoader.Plugins (ContractName = "PluginContract.IPlugin")' on the component 'MyApp.PluginLoader'.

I load my plugin as follows:

```
PluginLoader loader = new PluginLoader("Plugin");
        _Plugins = new Dictionary<string, IPlugin>();
        IEnumerable<IPlugin> plugins = loader.Plugins;
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: The exception message googles pretty well.  First hit is an SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9226712/17034  Whether you should allow a plugin to mess with the existing composition is a something you have to decide for yourself, could be a feature or could be a nasty bug.

Comment: Ok i have made that  : [ImportMany(AllowRecomposition=true)] , and that works but my new plugin does not appear with others, what do you have to add , an other load of my plugins Hans Passant ?

Comment: It is a completely different question, very poorly asked.  Click the Ask Question button.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help! but i dont have the right to speak during 2 day i dont now why ?